# apacite \cite alias

Tags: natbib, apa-style, apacite

I have been using the  `natbib` citation management package and the  bibliography style I use is `apalike`. I know that this is an old style and it is not up to date.

I want to change from `apalike` to `apacite`, but I have defined some citation aliases in `natbib` with `\defcitealias` that do not work when I change to `apacite`. Is there a solution for this? Does the `apacite` package have a command to set an alias?

Answer (score 1):

You claim that the citation aliasing mechanism of the `natbib` package doesn't work with the `apacite` package. This claim does not appear to be correct; all you have to do is load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` -- which you have to do anyway if you want to keep using `\citet` and `\citep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% create a sample bib file "on the fly"
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a:3000,
  author= "Anne Author", 
  title = "Thoughts",
  year  = 3000,
}
\end{filecontents}

%\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\defcitealias{a:3000}{B}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\defcitealias{a:3000}{B}

\begin{document}
\citet{a:3000}, \citetalias{a:3000}, \citepalias{a:3000}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a silly error when indicating the ```apacite``` package. I was able to solve it with your help.